# Item does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms

The new Form1() part of this code (this code is in my Main.cs) keeps giving me this error - HomeInventory2.Form1 does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

```
private void cDsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Form1();
    // show the form
    form.Show();
}
```

The Form1 code is as follows

```
namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1(IEnumerable<string> prepopulated)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
            textBoxAmount.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            textBoxCategories.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            textBoxProperties.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
            textBoxValue.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried just putting a blank constructor in there - but then of course when that button or menu item is called it just brings up a blank screen.

Comment: What does it have to do without any data?

Comment: Just add a empty `Form1()` constructor that inits with default values, i.e. same code as existing, just come up with sensible defaults. You can even factor the logic out to a function and call it from both constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes in .net have default constructors which don't take any arguments. When you are implementing your own constructor then the framework doesn't generate that empty constructor for your class. Same thing is happening here. in you `cDsToolStripMenuItem_Click` method you need to pass `IEnumerable<string>` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a constructor that takes no arguments like this

```
namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1(IEnumerable<string> prepopulated)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IEnumerable<String> lines = prepopulated;
            textBoxAmount.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            textBoxCategories.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            textBoxProperties.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
            textBoxValue.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IEnumerable<String> lines = null;
            textBoxAmount.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            textBoxCategories.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            textBoxProperties.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
            textBoxValue.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 I was going to anonymously sockpuppet this answer but then you went and called a method on `null`. I can't in good conscience support that.

Comment: Hey, I demonstrated how to mock up the constructor, but left it so he would see that there was some issue there. I wasn't going to go and create a new `IEnumerable<string>` and wasn't going to change all his logic ... Also, those are linq methods, they're designed to work with nulls ;-)

Comment: Oops, my bad :P Of course, trying to create a new `IEnumerable<string>` definitely wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the constructor for Form1:

```
public Form1(IEnumerable<string> prepopulated)
```

It's asking for a value of type `IEnumerable<string>` which you have to provide when you instatiate the form. Like this

```
IEnumerable<string> someValue;
.
.
// Actually assign a value to someValue
.
.
var form = new Form1(someValue);
```

You can also add a paremeterless constructor.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
```

The call to `InitializeComponent()` is used to basically populate your form with all controls and handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to supplier a param:

```
private void cDsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] prepopulated= ...;
    var form = new Form1(prepopulated);
    // show the form
    form.Show();
}
```

Either that or create a constructor without parameters.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide the `IEnumerable<string> prepopulated` input:

`make new Form1(null) or new From1(new List{"a","b"})`